# SVGR - Pass a prop to className?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm using [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/) to turn my SVG files into React components. I'm using an `svgo.config.js` file to pass a className to the SVG element via the `addClassesToSVGElement` plugin.

```
{
  name: 'addClassesToSVGElement`,
  params: {
    className: 'icon',
  },
},
```

What I'm struggling to figure out is how to pass a prop to that className. So instead of compiling to...

`const SVGName = (props) => (<svg className="icon" ... />)`

it compiles to ...

`` const SVGName = (props) => (<svg className={`icon ${props.extraIconClasses}`} ... />) ``

Is anyone aware of how to make this happen?

Comment: How exactly would you envision passing a prop to a class? Like you want to send to a class CSS lines or how? Could you write a line of code about how you would like it to work so that I understand your question, because I am not sure I got it.

Comment: Because you can't "pass" props to a className except for the way you wrote in the second line - by having in props the className name.

Comment: This question is specific to using SVGR. I can use the `addClassesToSVGElement` plugin for SVGO to add the `icon` class, but I can't figure out how add any classes passed in as props. I can only find info on using explicit strings. The answer may be that it is not possible.